# How to use custom css in extjs app

Tags: extjs

In my Extjs app I have kept custom.css file in the resources folder of the root for testing and in the build- resources folder. And add the css path to two both index.html files(test and build). But whenever I make it to convert to build production, index.html file overwrites and custom.css file finds missing. Somewhat problematic it is. I know that this is because I add this file externally. But Is there any permanent solutions to fix this, without violating the Extjs app structure ??

Comment: i don't think this is an extjs problem. It is just the way you have set up your project... i think

Comment: hi oliver. thanks for the reply.but the question is, where to keep the  custom css file in the app? Is there any convention in Extjs to use custom css file?

Comment: if you chose the way that u only include a css file - then u can store it in the resource folder.

Answer (score 1):

You can add your custom styles via scss. There are several articles around the web about styling your ExtJS app.

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.0/core_concepts/theming.html

http://www.rallydev.com/community/engineering/guide-custom-themes-extjs-4 [dead link]

If you only want to add your single custom css file - which i do not recommend - you can do things like that:

[Include an existing CSS file in custom extjs theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16465364/include-an-existing-css-file-in-custom-extjs-theme)

http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?270694-How-to-include-custom-components-CSS-in-build-CSS

Comment: thanks everyone for the reply. ultimately solved the problem with custon css file.but new problem occurs with the custom/external js file. I have kept this file in the resource folder and added it to app.json file. but when i am going to build it to production build fails... I don't know why??

Comment: what fails exactly? try to include the custom JS file outside of the <!-- <x-compile> --> ... <!-- </x-compile> --> marks in your index.html file. ( similar to the third link approach with the css ) i would not recommend using the app.json file for this.